# Web services with a large number of extensions

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soa

I need to design a traditional sort of "get customer by ID" SOAP service operation. The thing is that customer data is retrieved from about 15+ systems, and depending on the customer's geographical location, different data needs to come back in addition to the traditional base set of facts about a customer (name, address, phone number, etc).

There are therefore two types of customer information at hand:

- Common customer data that can fit into a "canonical data model" type bucket, e.g. name, address, etc.
- Region-specific customer data that is specific to a customer's region or country. Think social security number if you're in the U.S., National Insurance number if you're in the UK, and so on.

Customers can be from a wide range of regions and as a result if we were to follow the approach of a traditional customer base type and a number of extensions e.g. `USACustomerType` which extends the `CustomerType` base type, we'll quickly run into two issues:

1. The WSDL will be huge
2. The WSDL will have large bits of information that are irrelevant to large amounts of people

I'm trying to avoid both of these things.

The options I have thought of, all in my opinion quite mediocre, are:

1. Have only a base customer type and an unbounded list of name-value pairs, and different systems can add their own name-value pairs, and consumers looking for that data could look for those (this is nice and extensible, but just not a very good idea)
2. Bite the bullet and have a giant WSDL that has a `CustomerType` base type and a number of extensions, adding more nations as they become available
3. A variation on #2, which is have only a base `CustomerType` and a large number of optional fields

I suppose the question is: Have you run into a situation like this and if so, how did you deal with it?

Comment: The problem with name value pairs that you have to keep in mind that it will almost be impossible to validate that the data conforms to anything.

Comment: @Namphibian this is my problem. As soon as I decide to move to name-value pairs then validation goes out the window, and if you try to look for a property that isn't there then you just kind of have to deal with the fact that it's not there even if it's a mandatory field.

Comment: are you modelling your request and responses in the WSDL? Are you using XSD at all?

Comment: @Namphibian I'm definitely going to be using XSD to model this. The WSDL will just be referencing the XSD(s).